# Is it possible to obtain an yaml property at runtime?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

yaml is very convenient because you are getting a nice deserialization from yaml to java but in my case I need to be able to obtain the property value at runtime. Is there a way to accomplish this as if you were using .properties file instead, for example, just by having the property key value?

```
appName: myAppName
```

Here I'd like to obtain myAppName value at runtime using the snakeyaml library.

Comment: What library are you using to read that YAML?

Comment: What have you tried? What does not work? There should be a `yaml.get("appName")` I would imagine.

Comment: I wish however downvoted me would've explained what he/she is whinging about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes yaml.load() basically returns a java object so you can simply cast it to the appropriate type and get what you need:

```
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    String input = "{appName: myAppName, appVersion: myAppVerison}";
    Map yamlMap = (Map)yaml.load(input);
    assertEquals("myAppName", yamlMap.get("appName"));
```